# How can I stabilize my wireless internet connection if it keeps dropping?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, tcp

My current internet connection is very unstable. I'm using a Windows laptop connected to a 4G smartphone's Wi-Fi hotspot. The 4G signal is often so weak that it disconnects my phone from the network and that makes the hotspot close my open connections. It often happens that an image will load and halfway through the 4G signal will get too weak which will cause the image to stop loading, even if the signal is back a second later.

I have a secondary Windows laptop with a stable fiber connection that I could tunnel through (I have TeamViewer access). Is there any software that would stop my primary laptop Windows from disconnecting from the server if the phone's 4G connection drops for a short time? I remember browsing through VPN services and successfully using such a service (my secondary laptop wasn't needed) a few years ago, but I forgot the name of the VPN provider. Their client software would pretend to still be connected to the server if my 4G or WiFi dropped for less than a minute and their server-side software would do the same, giving my real connection plenty of time to re-establish.

Is there a VPN provider that can offer this kind of improved connection stability? Or, better, a tunelling solution that I could run on my primary and secondary laptops so I don't have to deal with a 3rd party VPN provider?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to ascertain exactly what is going on and what your expectations are.  I posit that when you loose and regain connectivity your IP address is changing and breaking your connection.

If that is the case, any UDP based VPN which does not change its IP address when reconnecting should do the trick. OpenVPN is ubitous and likely fits the bill. If you get a static IP address with it, so much the better. Most reputable VPN providers should be able to provide this. Its not trivial, but it is also definitely practical to run your own VPN server - and indeed some better spec routers tout this as a feature.

I comment that this is not a panacea - connection may not establish immediately - a few seconds after the VPN reestablishes is fairly typical.